# Выбор чекбоксов по id

Tags: javascript

Мне необходимо выбрать несколько чекбоксов по определенным id, и выдать определенное сообщение.
Не получается, чтобы при выборе конкретных чекбоксов шло сообщение.

```js
function sendcheck() {
  const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var idschecked = ["prodmag", "toch1", "avtno"];
  for (var i = 0; i < idschecked.length; index++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      alert('Получилось');
    } else {
      document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML = 'Пожалуйста, заполните форму!';
    }
    return idschecked;
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="prodmag" name="prodmag[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toch1" name="toch1[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toch2" name="toch2[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toch3" name="toch3[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="avtno" name="avtno[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>


<p><input type="button" value="Получить предложение" onClick="sendcheck()"></p>

<p id="alrt"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
```

---

задача так и не решена к сожалению.

Comment: У вас нету блока, куда выводить сообщение (`<div id="alert"><div>`). Подправьте строку `document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = 'Пожалуйста, заполните форму!';`. И второе функцию надо запустить - `sendcheck();`

Comment: Он есть)) добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил

```js
function sendcheck() {
  document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML='';
  var idschecked = ["prodmag", "toch1", "avtno"];
  var checked=0;
  for(i in idschecked){
    checked+=$(`#${idschecked[i]}:checked`).length;
  }
  if(checked==idschecked.length){
    alert('Получилось');
  }else{
    document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML = 'Пожалуйста, заполните форму!';
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="prodmag" name="prodmag[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toch1" name="toch1[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toch2" name="toch2[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toch3" name="toch3[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="avtno" name="avtno[]">
  <label>Название 1</label>
</div>


<p><input type="button" value="Получить предложение" onClick="sendcheck()"></p>

<p id="alrt"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
```

Comment: Нужно, чтобы при нажатии конкретных чекбоксов, вышло сообщение, т.е. в данном случае выделяю 3 чексбокса с этими id prodmag, toch1, avtno, нажимаю кнопку - выходит сообщение.

Comment: @Joseff исправил.

Comment: Отлично, все работает.

Comment: осталась неясность с заданием условия для разных id и соответственно вывода другого сообщения. т.е. основа теперь работает, не пойму как теперь добавить if else для использования  var idschecked2.

Comment: возможно нужно делать функцию в функции, только не пойму как корректно гасить функцию, если используется другой массив.

Comment: @Joseff а конкретно на примере что нужно сделать, а то не совсем пойму задачу. Может есть какой-то тестовый сайт у Вас, на нем покажите что надо сделать.

Comment: ок. сейчас включу

Comment: http://fatnev1.beget.tech/ - тут тестовая форма

Comment: пока не получается